# Update git branch after deleting a file from local system

Tags: git-commit, git-push, git

I have deleted a file in my local system. Now I would like to update the **locale branch + remote branch**. So that the file is removed from the remote branch as well.

I did

```
git add -u
```

It deletes the removed file from the local branch but the file still stays in remote branch.

How can I delete the file from remote branch too?

Comment: you need to push your changes to remove using git commit -m "Your message" and then `git push`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **removing the cached** files:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "cached problems"
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to **commit** your changes (the deletion of 1 file):

```
git commit -m "One file deletion"
```

And **push** it to remote branch:

```
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to push your changes to remove using. Ensure you pull the latest code first

```
git pull
git commit -m "Your message"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove a file from local repository should automatically reflect itself on the remote repository once you pushed it.

You first need to commit your changes though:

`git commit -m "Removed a file"`

And after that push your code with `git push`

If you want to keep your local file, but remove it from online you'll have to use the

`git rm <file-name> --cached`

as the answers above stated + you'll need to add it to your .gitignore file so any changes to that file would be ignored.